# CSS Keyframes - Snapping back to origin

Tags: css, css-animations

I am toggling a series of animations / transitions that I am triggering via a toggleClass with JQuery.

One of the animations is using the following:

```
.header {
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out
}

.depth .header {
  animation: movement .3s;
  animation-delay: .3s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

keyframes movement {
  100% { top: 0px }
}
```

At the end of the animation the div is snapping back to it's origin. Why is this?

[Here is a JSFiddle example of my issue.](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/4147qf6k/7/)

Comment: What browser are you using? I'm not experiencing this issue.

Comment: I'm seeing the snap-back in Chrome. I'm not seeing any sort of animation in Firefox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *animation-fill-mode: forwards;*

**This CSS property sets the state of the end animation when the animation is not running.**   
Otherwise the animation would end and you would just see the CSS properties applied in the non-animated element.

You can add to your .depth .header:

```
 -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
         animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

This is what you need here to persist the state of the animation. 
Just remember to define it in the class of the affected div that needs to be animated.

```
.depth .header {
    -webkit-animation: movement .3s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: .3s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -moz-animation: movement .3s;
    -moz-animation-delay: .3s;
    animation: movement .3s;
    animation-delay: .3s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

**JsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/4147qf6k/34/

[image]

Comment: Correct, for Firefox 5.0 (5.0) up to 16.0 (16.0) it needs the -moz prefix to work :)

Comment: Another quick question for you - Why is there snapping when removing the class in chrome / safari? http://codepen.io/MathiasaurusRex/pen/yydpBW

Comment: Have you tried to animate toggleClass for example (add jQuery UI) ? http://codepen.io/alexincarnati/pen/wBLyzB

Comment: Doesn't look like that resolves the issue. I'll keep playing with it.

Comment: Yes...I think check the amount of animations, and probably using reverse everywhere doesn't not help :)

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your CSS animation. `animation-fill-mode: forwards;`

> The target will retain the computed values set by the last keyframe
>   encountered during execution. The last keyframe encountered depends on
>   the value of animation-direction and animation-iteration-count:

**[Link to the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode)**

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4147qf6k/9/)

```
.depth .header {
    -webkit-animation: movement .3s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: .3s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation: movement .3s;
    animation-delay: .3s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
   animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```